# 'uvloop' has no attribute 'EventLoopPolicy'

Tags: python-3.x, uvloop

I am testing python code performance with uvloop. I am getting 'uvloop' has no attribute 'EventLoopPolicy' error.
I am using python 3.7 and
uvloop 0.13.0 
pycharm

I tried changing interpreter reinstalling  uvloop but none of them did not work.
Can anyone suggest what is the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're on a Mac, but I just fixed this problem on my CentOS7.x server by properly setting permissions to the `uvloop` Python package. It's pesky because (at least on CentOS) some pip-installed Python packages go in `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages` and some go in `/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages`.

Check out what the files in my `lib64` directory looked like before I fixed it:

```
me@myserver /usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages
$ ll
total 16
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 4096 Jan 17 15:38 click
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root  134 Jan 17 15:38 Click-7.0.dist-info
drwxr-x---. 4 root root   74 Jan 17 15:42 httptools
drwxr-x---. 2 root root  141 Jan 17 15:42 httptools-0.0.13-py3.6.egg-info
drwxr-x---. 3 root root 4096 Jan 17 15:43 pydantic
drwxr-x---. 2 root root  111 Jan 17 15:43 pydantic-1.3.dist-info
drwxr-x---. 5 root root 4096 Jan 17 15:43 uvloop
drwxr-x---. 2 root root  141 Jan 17 15:43 uvloop-0.14.0-py3.6.egg-info
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root 4096 Jan 17 15:38 websockets
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root  134 Jan 17 15:38 websockets-8.1.dist-info
```

Unless I was running as a root user the uvloop files are untouchable and that's what caused the error. On your Mac, try to find where your `uvloop` package is installed and make sure your script can access it.

Comment: You shouldn't be installing any packages system-wide anyway, but use either user site-packages directories or virtualenvs.

Answer (score 0):

Rename your own file to something else than `uvloop.py`, such as `test_uvloop.py`.

You're confusing Python's import machinery by having your own file the same name as the library you're trying to use.

Comment: This the right answer for question/situation as posed by OP and should be accepted. Leaving my answer up, however, for people who, like me, arrived here by googling the error message.